# Multi Select Search Bar

Tags: usability, website-design, web-app, ux-field, ux-designer

I have boolean search bar and a user want to make search in a param, b param, c param but this is good for single category selection to sho

Comment: Tushar, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I don't understand your question - what do you call a "boolean search bar"? And what is your questions - text seems to be cut off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.